# hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter gets fired twice

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to change the content of a block when a specific node is displayed. The code works fine.
BUT
the hook custom_block_view_block_1_alter gets called twice.
that is GOT MY NODE is displayed twice.
How come?

```
<?php
/**
* Implementation of custom hook_node_load
*/

$count=0;
function custom_node_load($nodes,$types){        
  foreach($nodes as $key =>$node){       
    if($node->type=="person"){         
      drupal_set_message("Person Node loaded");
      $customised_value="WAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA";
      $node->customised = $customised_value;
      variable_set('my_person_node',$node);
      drupal_set_message("WAHAHA");      
    }       
  }        
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter
*/
function custom_block_view_block_1_alter(&$data, $block) {    
  global $count;
  if($block->delta=="1"){
    ++ $count;
    $block->title="HERHE";
    $my_nodes=variable_get('my_person_node');
    dpm($block);
    $data['subject']="HEHE";
    $data['content']="<strong>".$my_nodes->customised."</strong>";
    drupal_set_message("GOT MY NODE".$count);
  }    
}
```

Comment: tell really what you want to do?

Comment: Could it be because the block it self is displayed twice? If not, can you work around the problem by caching the block? Please update Q with the two backtraces, `dpm(debug_backtrace())`, so we can determine why it's being called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue recently and the problem was the team had created both a module and a theme with the same name so Drupal was executing the same hook twice (once for the module and once for the theme). Renaming the theme solved the problem.

Comment: Yes that was the problem